# How can I manage the CPU usage of Tomcat's reloadable="true" setting?

Tags: java, tomcat

How can I *manage* the CPU usage of Tomcat's `reloadable="true"` setting?  When the feature is enabled, I'm observing a pattern in one of the Catalina threads of 10 seconds of high CPU usage followed by a 10 second sleep, which is causing my laptop's CPU fan to run continuously at high speed.  I can stop that by setting `reloadable="false"`, but I'm using this machine for development the feature is useful for that.

Is it possible to set `reloadable="true"`, but reduce its CPU usage?  Perhaps by increasing the sleep period or by somehow lowering the intensity its scan for changes to reload?

---

For reference, here are the docs on the setting I'm talking about:

https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/context.html#Attributes:

> Set to true if you want Catalina to monitor classes in
>   /WEB-INF/classes/ and /WEB-INF/lib for changes, and automatically
>   reload the web application if a change is detected. This feature is
>   very useful during application development, but it requires
>   significant runtime overhead and is not recommended for use on
>   deployed production applications. That's why the default setting for
>   this attribute is false. You can use the Manager web application,
>   however, to trigger reloads of deployed applications on demand.

I haven't seen any obvious ways to control this other than turning it completely off.

Comment: Set reload to false and *use the Manager web application, however, to trigger reloads of deployed applications on demand*

Comment: I already saw *and quoted* that.  It also doesn't answer my question.  I'd like the reloads to still happen automatically, just less frequently or in a way that uses the CPU less intensely.

Comment: I understood that, and it is not something you can control except as you've already documented.

Comment: That, on the other hand, does answer my question.  Hopefully they'll add features to do that in the future.

Comment: Well, they did document that *it requires significant runtime overhead and is not recommended for use on deployed production applications* precisely because it uses a lot of CPU to provide auto reloading. You could potentially speed your workflow up by using [hot code replace](https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_What_is_hot_code_replace%3F) (assuming your IDE has that) or a tool like JRebel.